# mysql - create view checks other table have value

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, left-join, sql-view

I have these two tables.

```
  tbl_s
  +------+---------+
  | s_id | s_name  |
  +------+---------+
  |   1  |  foo    |
  |   2  |  bar    |
  |   3  |  doe    |
  +------+---------+

  tbl_j
  +------+------+----------+
  | j_id | s_id | j_status |
  +----- +------+----------+
  |    1 |    1 |    0     |
  |    2 |    1 |    0     |
  |    3 |    1 |    1     |
  |    4 |    3 |    0     |
  |    5 |    2 |    2     |
  +------+------+----------+
```

I would like to make a view (without sub-query) that checks whether at least one j_status value != 0 in the table tbl_j
This should be the result

```
  vw_s
  +------+---------+-----+
  | s_id | s_name  | chk |
  +------+---------+-----+
  |   1  |  foo    |  Y  |
  |   2  |  bar    |  Y  |
  |   3  |  doe    |  N  |
  +------+---------+-----+
```

I tried with IF but without success.
How could I do?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your desired output just like you did for the input tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and aggregation:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_s
SELECT 
    s.s_id, 
    s.s_name,
    CASE WHEN MAX(j.j_status != 0) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END chk
FROM tbl_s s
LEFT JOIN tbl_j j ON s.s_id = j.s_id
GROUP BY s.s_id, s.s_name
```

Note: I don't know why you mentionned that this has to be done without subqueries. One other solution would be to use an inline query with a `NOT EXISTS` condition. THis avoids the need for aggregation:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_s
SELECT 
    s.s_id, 
    s.s_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_j j WHERE s.s_id = j.s_id AND j.j_status != 0) 
        THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' 
    END chk
FROM tbl_s s
```

Comment: yeah, you are right..it should work with the OP's sample input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below way -

```
select  a.s_id ,s_name,case when sum(j_status)=0 then 'N' else 'Y' end as chk
from tbl_s a inner join tbl_j b on a.s_id =b.s_id 
group by a.s_id ,s_name
```